# hip flexor stretch and popping sound

Tags: flexibility

I used to practice Taekwondo before, my hips would pop when I externally rotate my  hips after sitting for long and I assumed it was normal. No pain or snapping, just a pop like you might hear when you stretch yourself out after being a position for long. Now, I have starting working on my flexibility again. I have found the same popping has resumed after I started stretching hip flexors. Is this normal?

Comment: What I'm gradually getting to know from online resources is that if we find popping associated with increase in flexibility, it is a sign that flexibility and strength of muscles around the joint aren't in balance. Will see a PT soon...

Answer (score 1):

*Do not take medical advice from strangers on the Internet.*

Please see a medical doctor or/and a physiotherapist.  If you have access to a physiotherapist that specialises in sport injuries, that would be good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Go see a physiotherapist. Right away.

My wife, a dance teacher, showed the same symptoms and it turned out to be torn tendons. It needed to be corrected with minor surgery. Hopefully this is not your problem, but definitely get it looked at before it turns into something serious. If you're lucky, you just need a cortisone injection.